# Modify for command to remove number from end of file name

Tags: shell, regular-expression, filenames, wildcards

All,

I have been messing with the for command to remove patterns from file names in bulk.

Example file name:

```
:Common:CBE.key_44643_1
```

I can use the following command to remove the :Common: portion.

```
for f in *; do mv "$f" "${f#:Common:}";done
```

For the life of me I cannot get the command to remove everything to the right of .key. Below is my attempt

```
for f in *; do mv "$f" "$(?<=crt)(?s)(.*$);done
```

The command runs but no change to the file. I am running this on a mac.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the file names don't contain newlines or backslashes:

```
for f in ./*
do
  mv "$f" "$(echo "$f" | sed 's/key_.*$/key/')
done
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it with shell:

```
for f in *; do
    mv -- "$f" "${f%.key*}.key"
done
```

Comment: Excuse the ignorance but am I am to just run these from the command line like: for f in *; do mv "$f" "$(echo $f | sed 's/key_.*$/key/');done